# Is it possible to set up a REST data source on apex.oracle.com with OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex

I'm attempting to add a REST data source from Xero.com to my app on apex.oracle.com. I've confirmed my credentials work properly when connecting to Xero's Oauth2 api from elsewhere, but I can't connect from the REST data source wizard. I suspect this is because the authorized redirect URI I am providing to Xero is incorrect. I have been providing the URL "https://apexea.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_authentication.callback" as recommended by [this guide](https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1709/).

Is there another callback URL I should be using, or, if not, another method then the REST data source wizard by which to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, REST Data Sources only support the OAuth2 "Client Credentials" flow, which does not involve any browser redirects.
For redirect-based OAuth flows like "Implicit Grant" or "Authorization Code", there is no declarative access; so you would need to implement custom PL/SQL code in order to get the token. Also the callback endpoint would beed to be provided by you, e.g. as a REST service or an "AJAX Callback".